# Current location with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am having issue with retrieve the current location.

**Step 1:**
when i press a button it will open the default popup for enable the location service,as i inspected it doesn't enable the location.

**Step 2:**
If i enable the location manually i am getting the current location,if i do the first step it doesn't work

```
       final Location location = Location();

  LocationData _location;
  String _error;

  Future<void> _getLocation() async {
    setState(() {
      _error = null;
    });
    try {
      final LocationData _locationResult = await location.getLocation();
      setState(() {
        _location = _locationResult;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (err) {
      setState(() {
        _error = err.code;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: I suggest you use the location package https://pub.dev/packages/location

Comment: i am getting the location if i do manually enable but if i do step 1it doesn't work do you know what is the reason or .can share some sample code @ByteMe

Comment: I have been trying to the with location plugin you suggested,but it does't work,`https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/blob/master/location/example/lib/get_location.dart`,i am trying with the their github.but it throws like this error.`2 postional argument expected but  0 found` @ByteMe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample of how to get the location using the location package

```dart
Future _getLocation() async {
    Location location = new Location();
    LocationData _pos = await location.getLocation();
    SharedPrefrence().setLatitude(_pos.latitude);
    SharedPrefrence().setLongitude(_pos.longitude);
}
```

Learn more about setting up the package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/location#usage)

Comment: i did try to use this but when i `Location location = new Location();` and import package then `Location location = new Location();` in this line it show error like this `2 postional argument expected but  0 found` @ByteMe

Comment: hmm, could you update your question with the code of where you tried this

Comment: @Morbius can you stop your application and do `flutter clean && flutter run` and then check? Keep the code as is `Location location = new Location()`

Comment: i already did that,but it doesn't allow me to run the app @Alok

Comment: Don't worry @Morbius, let us do something to make it work. Is that working now or you have left it for sometime? Can you help me with the error, you are facing when you are running the app?

Comment: `Location location = new Location();` on this line this the error even if i imported the required pacakages
`2 postional argument expected but  0 found`,before that i tried with geolocator it is working but you need to manually enable location service even if it is asking permission to access location when i press allow it doesn't enable the location . @Alok

Comment: @Morbius, if you don't mind can you share the GitHub repo for the same, or if not. Can you create a dummy project with just `Location package` in it with a single page, and upload it to Github for me. It will be long process for you, but would help you in great extent. I hope you understand, but I am tryna help you in a best possible way. **Share the link here itself**. We will not be extending `ByteMe` answer's comment further. Just the link, and we will work on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218953/discussion-between-morbius-and-alok).

Answer (score 3):

As i inspected the problem was used by two packages called

`flutter_google_places: ^0.2.6`

`geocoder: ^0.2.1`

On the page, The `Location location = new Location()` in this location is used by the two packages, so the packages get correlated.

Because I have two buttons one for getting the current location and one for searching for a custom location.

So what I did was **in import  I had to add a prefix and use some functions along with prefix name to search location function**, now it's working very well.
Now it's asking for permission and showing the dialogue box to enable the location without leaving the app

Thanks to @Alok and @ByteMe for helping me out

```
import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart' as google_place;
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart' as map_service;
import 'package:location/location.dart';
    
//Current Location Function

      Future _getLocation() async {
        Location location = new Location();
        LocationData _currentPosition = await location.getLocation();
        SharedPrefrence().setLatitude(_currentPosition.latitude.toString());
        SharedPrefrence().setLongitude(_currentPosition.longitude.toString());
       
        Future loginstatus = SharedPrefrence().getLogedIn();
      
          loginstatus.then((data) {
            if (data == true) {
              Navigator.pop(context, true);
              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
                  ModalRoute.withName("/login"));
            } else {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
                ),
              );
            }
          });
        
      }
```

Comment: Congratulations Morbius. My vote for your effrots :)

Comment: Thanks man,if you haven't told me to try the solution as separate project i wouldn't know that ,@Alok

Comment: That is why we are here Morbius. Welcome to the real developer's life :) All the very best

Comment: ✌✌@Alok @ByteMe

Comment: You can vote **ByteMe's answer**, if you liked his answer. Later you can mark your answer as correct. I guess after 24 hours, you will allowed to do so

Comment: superb.. the only solution worked for me .. thumbs up.