# How to reduce size for my won png in marker?

Tags: flutter, geolocation

await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 3.2),
'images/Icon_Parking_Pin_Location.png');
setState(() {
this.mapMarker = mapMarker;
});

Comment: Duplicate of [Current location with flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177329/current-location-with-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add geolocation package in pupspec.yaml and importing libaray in your dart file. Just call this function{getCurrentLocation()} in your {initstate()} function.

```
getCurrentLocation(){
    final geoPosition = Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: 
    LocationAccuracy.high);
    return geoPosition;
  }
```